# creating a dialog in device admin

Tags: android, dialog, device, alert

i am experiencing problem in creating a dialog in device admin receiver.

Error: unable to add window--token null is not for an application.

i just want to create a dialog which verifies a password stored in my preferences, if it matches then you can disable device admin check box else it should exit..

any ideas

```
public static class DeviceAdminSampleReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
        void showToast(Context context, String msg) {
            //String status = context.getString(R.string.admin_receiver_status, msg);
          //  Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



        @Override
        public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
            showMyDialog(context);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public void showMyDialog(final Context context){
            AlertDialog dialog = null;
            SharedPreferences prefs= context.getSharedPreferences("MainPrefs", 0);
            final String tempPass = prefs.getString("password", "");

            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View deviceDialog = factory.inflate(R.layout.device_receiver_layout, null);
           final EditText input = (EditText) deviceDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_editText);
            Button done = (Button) deviceDialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            Button cancel = (Button) deviceDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            builder.setView(deviceDialog);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle("Ultimate SMS Password");
            //builder.show();
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if(tempPass.regionMatches(0, input.getText().toString(), 0, tempPass.length()))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Matches", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Not Matches", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //finish();

                }
                }
            });

            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });     
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I request you that before posting a question directly here try to Google it from your side and share your search result

Comment: Used you Context Application or Activity? Can we see your implementation please?

Comment: I am a regular reader of SO and researched a lot, its just that i decided to join this amazing group yesterday. Anyways, My application contains a checkbox which enables/diables my app as an admin app. My Admin receiver class is a basic one which notifies the user that his app is Admin enabled or not.

Comment: throrin 19 yes i used a simple activity, and that activity has this deviceadminSampleReceiver as a static class

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show a dialog on non-activity context. But, You can design a transparent activity to make it look like dialog and call it from **Device Admin** as following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

context declared in the code above is an attribute for any action method inside `DeviceAdminReceiver` class. For better understanding check following:

```
@Override
public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent intentcl = new Intent(context, OperationActivity.class);
    intentcl.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intentcl);
    return super.onDisableRequested(context, intent);
}
```